# Clusterize similar words / values in R

Tags: r, grouping, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Say I have the following variable

```
ChicKen120
Chicken1.20
Chicken(1.20)
Cow
cow.
cow/
cat
```

As you can see there are many typos. 
What I would like to do is make groups of similar words and automatically redefine each group.

i.e.

```
group 1 = "Cow", "cow", "cow/2

group 2 = "ChicKen120", "Chicken1.20"
```

After formatting each group, the end result will be

```
chicken(1.20)
chicken(1.20)
chicken(1.20)
cow
cow
cow
cat
```

### My current progress

I have found groups of similar words by using `adist()`

```
#Run adist on to find all words that are similar to another words. 
text <- c("ChicKen120","Chicken1.20","Chicken(1.20)","Cow","cow.", "cow/", "cat")
    > adist(text)
            [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
    [1,]    0    2    4    9    9    9    9
    [2,]    2    0    2   10    9   10   10
    [3,]    4    2    0   12   11   12   12
    [4,]    9   10   12    0    2    2    3
    [5,]    9    9   11    2    0    1    3
    [6,]    9   10   12    2    1    0    3
    [7,]    9   10   12    3    3    3    0
```

As you can see, similar words have a distance of less than 4 and dissimilar words have a distance of more than 4.

How can I clusterize these results into groups which can then be redefined?

For example, I've was given the following piece of advice:
*"I used lapply() and unique() to clusterize this feature. After it, I just look for centroids and used table() for scoring, like a retrieve internet information system does. For example:*

*"chocolate", "chcolate", "chocolatebar", "choc bar", "chocolate bar" are all automatically reidentified as 'chocolate'.*

*All of this was done with native library."*

However, I am a beginner in R and a layman in mathematics so i'm not sure how to approach the clustering and re-defining of groups.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your approach, you can continue clustering like this

```
text <- c("ChicKen120","Chicken1.20","Chicken(1.20)","Cow","cow.", "cow/", "cat")
mat <- adist(text)
rownames(mat) <- colnames(mat) <- text

d <- as.dist(mat)
hc <- hclust(d, method = "average")
plot(hc)

k <- 2 # choose a 2-cluster-solution
rect.hclust(hc, k=k)
clusters <- cutree(hc, k=k)
split(text, clusters)
# $`1`
# [1] "ChicKen120"    "Chicken1.20"   "Chicken(1.20)"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "Cow"  "cow." "cow/" "cat"
```

Comment: Would it possible to comment /explain what is going on and why it's happening, so I understand the nuts and bolts?

Comment: as.dist converts your matrix into a distance matrix. This can be processed by hclust, which performs a hierarchical cluster analysis. Plot plots a dendrogram, rect draws rectangles around the 2 clusters, cutree gets the clusters for each observation and split splits the observations by cluster.

Comment: If I have a variable with 10000s of words rather than the above example of 7, how can I choose the size of the cluster? Is there an automatic method for determining cluster sizes?

Comment: When run on my large character vector, I receive the following message `mat <- adist(text)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3181.9 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In adist(text) :
  Reached total allocation of 8052Mb: see help(memory.size)`   
Is there a work around to achieve the same goal with a large vector?

Comment: Have you found one? Or can you think of one?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with case-sensitive output. If the letters in the words are in different case, the resulting clusters are erroneous. So I have used the following to solve the problem: `sapply(list, tolower)`